# Dell monitor U2715H turns itself off while watching a movie

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

How to prevent Dell external monitor U2715H to turns itself off while watching a movie?

Sometimes it shuts off after 30 min sometimes after 1 hour. And after it shuts off I can't turn it on by moving a mouse or pressing any keys on keyboard, I have to unplug it and plug it again to my Mac to make it work again.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two things that might be responsible for this:

- Faulty monitor
- OS setting

Don't know much about mac, but there should be a setting somewhere that allows you to change the screen timeout / screen lock setting.

If you've tried that and still have the problem, I'd test with another monitor. Especially the fact that you need to replug it in order to get it to work again seems a litte fishy.

Comment: I don't know of any setting that would sleep just one monitor of a multi-setup, so I'd be inclined to think hardware too. One test might be to try watching on VLC, which prevents sleep whilst playing, just in case it is a player issue.

Comment: Agree, wasn't really sure what he meant with multiple monitor, considering he's using the Dell as an external monitor to (supposedly) his macbook. Not really sure if there are more than one standalone monitor. Either way, testing the OS settings first can't hurt.

Comment: I have dual monitors here [though both 'external' as I'm on a Mac Pro]. There are no independent monitor 'sleep' settings of any kind. Possibly it may be different on a laptop, but I can't test. Always worth a look in Energy Saver or Displays, though, just in case it's different on lappies. Let's see what the OP comes back with.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Gonna try it out when be back home from work. By the way I use VLC player and have only one external monitor that is plugged to MacBook Pro, Sorry for not being clear in my question. Again, thank you and gonna try it out later.

Comment: Also, unplug the video cable at both ends, and blow in it, then plug it back in. Maybe its a contact issue.